# ElasticSearch brings up less relevant results when scoring is applied

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring

I have an index in ElasticSearch 0.9 with some documents like this:

```
{"Id":1, "Title":"Hello World" , "Popularity":1},

{"Id":2, "Title":"Hello World" , "Popularity":3},

{"Id":3, "Title":"Hello" , "Popularity":10}
```

As you see the first two documents have the same title text but different popularity values. Now I do a Fuzzy search on the Title property with a simple scoring script in place:

Scoring script : "_score * doc['Popularity'].value"

My query is something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_score": {
      "lang": "mvel",
      "script": "_score * doc['Popularity'].value",
      "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
          "Title": {
            "value": "Hello World",
            "fuzziness": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now what happens is that the third document (whose Id is equal to 3) comes to the top of the search result simply because it has a higher popularity. In the other words the scoring function completely overrides the relevancy of the search result. Whereas I expect to see the more relevant documents (Id = 1 and 2) on the top because they are more relevant to the search term (shorter distance) and then between the two top search results the scoring function boost the document with a higher popularity value. So the result would I expect would be like this:

```
{"Id":2, "Title":"Hello World" , "Popularity":3}
{"Id":1, "Title":"Hello World" , "Popularity":1}
{"Id":3, "Title":"Hello" , "Popularity":10}
```

As a real world example, we have a music store which has a search bar on the top. Users may enter a keyword such as "Blue" and then there will be tens of music tracks whose title is "Blue" and some other which are close to the search time (e.g. "BlueSky"). Each track has a popularity property as well however we want to see all the tracks whose title is "Blue" on the top even the track with title of "BlueSky" has a higher popularity simply because the users prefer to see the exact matches first. Then those whose title is exactly "Blue" must be ranked by the scoring script.

Can someone please guide me as to how can I update my query so that the relevant result (regardless of scoring) still get to the top of the result list and then among them scoring boost the more popular ones?

Comment: Why don't let you ES do its job by default, meaning use your fuzzy query or whatever (without your custom score) and then do a `sort` based on default scoring, and if this scoring is equal then do the sort based on the popularity. From you samples, it seems you don't really want your popularity to get into the scoring, or if you do it has a wrong thinking behind doing it like you do now.

Comment: Because we only fetch 100 documents (e.g. 100 music tracks) when we search (this is a requirement) and so if we don't apply scoring more popular items may not get fetched. For example if there were 101 music tracks with title "Beat It", the very famous Micheal Jackson's beat it song might be the 101th one and so it won't be included in the search result. Now bo matter how we sort, the most popular song won't be found.